# How to use mocha tests with async.series

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, mocha.js

I'm trying to use async.series to control flow asynchronous mocha tests like this but the callback() doesn't seem to ever be executed as it only does the first test and never outputs the log message in the end callback. It seems as if after `done()` is called in the external test it returns back to execute the console.log correctly, but maybe it just recognize what `callback` references?:

```
describe('auth test' ,function(){

    async.series([
        function(callback){
            //TEST: login user : POST bad login
            it('1'), function(done){
               test1(done, 'path',  function(rdy){  //this test is in a separate module
                    console.log(1);
                    callback(null);
                });
            });
        },
        function(callback){
            it('2'), function(done){
               test2(done, 'path',  function(rdy){    //this test is in a separate module
                    console.log(2);
                    callback(null);
                });
            });
        }
    ],
     function(err){
        console.log('tests done');
    });
});
```

Output is:

```
<mocha test result for test 1>
1
```

Comment: Test the .series rather than putting the `it` in individual functions - or better, write multiple tests.

Comment: What you are showing in your question is not syntactically correct JavaScript. `it('1'), function(done) {...` makes no sense. You've got unbalanced brackets in there.

Comment: the callback works when it's placed outside of the `it`, problem being that it gets called before the test finishes.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm stuck at exactly the same issue: using async.series with mocha

Answer (score 0):

You are using asynchronous tests without ever calling the callbacks. If you really need to synchronize your tests, you could just use Mocha synchronously (without callbacks)

```
it ('1', function() {
  test1('path',  function(rdy) {
    console.log(1);
    callback();
  });
});
```

Comment: what does that have to do with async.series callback not working though? `done()` is being called from inside the external tests (test1(), test2())

Comment: I haven't seen any `done()` calls in the original code. As for `async.series` callback, it's really hard to say why it's not firing (well, actually, because the second `series` callback is not firing at the beginning) without seeing the whole picture, especially the second test.